# Extracting variables from array and insert into mysql

Tags: php, arrays

UPDATED MY POST 6/15/14 my new issue is that I have checkboxes next to each text input which will indicate (if checked) that the text in the textbox is the correct answer. However when I make a change in which checkbox is checked for a paticular answer it is not being saved correctly.

Here is my full UPDATED code

```
  <?php
                           //if save was clicked
                             if(isset($_POST['saveit']))
                               {
                                 $tmodnameid = $_POST['tmodnameid'];
                                 $tmodnameid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $tmodnameid);
                                 $quizpercent = $_POST['quizpercent'];
                                 $quizpercent = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $quizpercent);

                                 mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE training_quizs set tmoduleid='$tmodnameid', quiz_passingpercent='$quizpercent'  
                                              WHERE quizid='$quid'");

                                 //lets delete all questions and answers since we are re-saving them
                                 $q = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT qarowid FROM training_quizs_questions WHERE quizid='$quid'");
                                 while($qqr = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
                                 {
                                    $qarowid = $qqr['qarowid'];
                                    mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE from training_quizs_answers WHERE qarowid='$qarowid'");
                                 }
                                 mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE from training_quizs_questions WHERE quizid='$quid'");


                                 $n = 0;
                                 $newquestion = $_POST['newquestion'];
                                  foreach($newquestion as $aquestion)
                                           { 

                                             mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_questions(quizid, qquestion)
                                                          VALUES('$quid','$aquestion')");
                                             $questionrowid = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

                                             //lets save each of this questions answers

                                             //save first potential answer for this question
                                               $answera = $_POST['answera'][$n];
                                               $isanswera ='';
                                               $isanswera = trim($_POST['isanswera'][$n]);
                                               if(!empty($isanswera))
                                               {
                                                 $isanswera ='yes'; 
                                                 $firstsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answera','$isanswera')");
                                               }else{
                                                 $isanswera = '';  
                                                 $firstsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answera',' ')");
                                               }



                                             //save second potential answer for this question
                                               $answerb = $_POST['answerb'][$n];
                                               $isanswerb='';
                                               $isanswerb = trim($_POST['isanswerb'][$n]);
                                              if(!empty($isanswerb))
                                               {
                                                 $isanswerb ='yes'; 
                                                  mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerb','$isanswerb')");
                                               }else{
                                                 $isanswerb = ''; 
                                                  mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerb',' ')");
                                               }


                                             //save third potential answer for this question
                                               $answerc = $_POST['answerc'][$n];
                                               $isanswerc = trim($_POST['isanswerc'][$n]);
                                               if(!empty($isanswerc))
                                               {
                                                 $isanswerc ='yes'; 
                                                 mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerc','$isanswerc')");
                                               }else{
                                                 $isanswerc = ''; 
                                                 mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerc',' ')");
                                               }


                                            //save fourth potential answer for this question
                                               $answerd = $_POST['answerd'][$n];
                                               $isanswerd = trim($_POST['isanswerd'][$n]);
                                               if(!empty($isanswerd))
                                               {
                                                mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerd','yes')");
                                               }else{
                                                mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerd',' ')");
                                               }
                                            //save fifth potential answer for this question
                                               $answere = $_POST['answere'][$n];
                                               $isanswere = trim($_POST['isanswere'][$n]);
                                               if(!empty($isanswere))
                                               {
                                                mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answere','yes')");
                                               }else{
                                                mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answere',' ')");
                                               }
                                            //save sixth potential answer for this question
                                               $answerf = $_POST['answerf'][$n];
                                               $isanswerf = trim($_POST['isanswerf'][$n]);
                                               if(!empty($isanswerf))
                                               {
                                               mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerf','yes')");
                                               }else{
                                               mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT into training_quizs_answers(qarowid, answer, isanswer) 
                                                            VALUES('$questionrowid','$answerf',' ')");
                                               }
                                               $n++;
                                           }
                                             //get rid of any blank rows that were created 
                                               mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE from training_quizs_answers WHERE answer=''");

                                 echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>                
                                           <h4>Success!</h4>
                                            You successfully setup a new quiz from the training module.
                                       </div>";

                               }

                                //lets get the questions
                                  $qsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM training_quizs WHERE quizid='$quid' LIMIT 1");
                                  $qsqlrow = mysqli_fetch_array($qsql);
                                  extract($qsqlrow);
                                  $quiz_createdon = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($quiz_createdon));
                         ?>
                         <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1' id='form1'>
                         <div class="row-form clearfix">
                            <div class="span4">
                               Training Module Name 
                               <select name='tmodnameid'>
                                 <?php
                                    //lets select all training modules that have not quiz yet
                                      $atlistsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT tmoduleid, tmodule_name FROM training_modules WHERE 
                                                                tmoduleid='$tmoduleid' LIMIT 1");
                                      $atlistrow = mysqli_fetch_array($atlistsql);
                                      $tmoduleid = $atlistrow['tmoduleid'];
                                      $tmodule_name = $atlistrow['tmodule_name'];
                                      echo "<option value='$tmoduleid'>$tmodule_name</option>";

                                      $tlistsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT tmoduleid, tmodule_name FROM training_modules WHERE tmoduleid !='$tmoduleid' 
                                                               ORDER by tmodule_name desc");
                                      while($tlistrow = mysqli_fetch_array($tlistsql))
                                        {
                                          $tmoduleid = $tlistrow['tmoduleid'];
                                          $tmodule_name = stripslashes($tlistrow['tmodule_name']);
                                          echo "<option value='$tmoduleid'>$tmodule_name</option>";
                                        }
                                 ?>
                               </select>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="span2">
                               Percent needing to pass<br /> 
                               <input type='text' name='quizpercent' style='width:50px' maxlength='3' value='<?php echo "$quiz_passingpercent";?>'></strong>%</strong>
                            </div>
                         </div> 

                         <div class="row-form clearfix">
                             <?php 
                                $question_num = 1;
                                //lets list all the questions
                                  $qsql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM training_quizs_questions WHERE quizid='$quid' ORDER BY qarowid asc");
                                  while($qrow = mysqli_fetch_array($qsql))
                                   {
                                     extract($qrow);
                                     $qquestion = stripslashes($qquestion);
                                     echo "<strong>$question_num)</strong><br /><textarea name='newquestion[]'>$qquestion</textarea><br />
                                           <br /><strong>Question $question_num Potential Answers</strong><br />";

                                     //lets get all the potential answers
                                       $numpotentialanswers = 0;
                                       $letter = 'a';
                                       $displayletter = 'A';
                                       $qaaql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM training_quizs_answers WHERE qarowid='$qarowid' 
                                                             ORDER by answerrow ASC");
                                                while($qarow = mysqli_fetch_array($qaaql))
                                                  {
                                                     extract($qarow);
                                                     $answer = stripslashes($answer);
                                                     $numpotentialanswers++;

                                                     if($isanswer =='yes')
                                                       {
                                                         $checked ='checked';
                                                       }
                                                       else
                                                       {
                                                         $checked ='';
                                                       }
                           $answerletter[] = "answer$letter";
                           $isanswerletter[] = "isanswer$letter";

                                            ?>
                                               <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> <?php echo "$displayletter";?>) 
                                                   <input type='text' <?php echo "name='answer" . $letter. "[]'"; ?> value='<?php echo "$answer";?>' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                           </div>
                                                           <div style='float:left'>
                                                              is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswer<?php echo "$letter";?>[]' value='yes' <?php echo "$checked";?>>
                                                           </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                          <?php
                                                     $letter++;
                                                     $displayletter++;
                                                  }
                                          //lets display the additional potential answer rows
                                          if($numpotentialanswers == 1)
                                            {
                                                echo "<div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> B) 
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerb[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerb[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> C) 
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerc[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerc[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> D)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerd[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerd[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> E)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answere[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> F)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerf[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>";
                                            }
                                          if($numpotentialanswers == 2)
                                            {
                                                echo "<div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> C)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerc[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerc[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> D)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerd[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerd[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> E)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answere[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> F)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerf[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      ";
                                            }
                                          if($numpotentialanswers == 3)
                                            {
                                                echo "<div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> D)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerd[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerd[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> E)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answere[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> F)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerf[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      ";
                                            }
                                          if($numpotentialanswers == 4)
                                            {
                                                echo "<div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> E) 
                                                           <input type='text' name='answere[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswere[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      <div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> F)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerf[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      ";
                                            }
                                          if($numpotentialanswers == 5)
                                            {
                                               echo "<div style='float:left; padding-right:4px'> F)
                                                           <input type='text' name='answerf[]' style='width:400px'><br /><br />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div style='float:left'>
                                                           is answer <input type='checkbox' name='isanswerf[]' value='yes'>
                                                      </div><div style='clear:both'></div>
                                                      ";
                                            }
                                      $question_num++;
                                   }

                             ?>
                             <br />
                             <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add Question" /><br />
                             <div id='text'></div>                          
                         </div>


                        <div class="footer tar">
                            <input type='submit' name='saveit' value='Save' is='submit' class='btn'></form>
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
```

Comment: Ask `mysqli_error()` if your queries actually succeeded.

Comment: mysqli_error() does not display any error and the first character for each textbox is being inserted into the database so I would not expect an error to be returned. I think my error is with the php itself although I can not spot it.

Comment: Your question does not contain any information about the actual form, or `$_POST` structure. Also `error_reporting`.

Comment: I updated my post to have the form code in it. My issue is I am not getting any error message instead what is happening is that only the first character of each text input is being saved in the database. So no matter what I type in each text box in the form only the first character from each text box is being saved in the mysql. I tried getting an error from mysqli_error() to display but non gets displayed. Also my error_log file does not seem to have anything either which is why I am hoping another pair of eyes may be able to spot what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

None of your form fields have array `names[]`, so accessing `$_POST['answera'][$n]` will just extract one letter.

Comment: Thank you Mario. I made a change but now get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) which is on the line where I have <input type='text' name='$answerletter[]' value='$answer' style='width:400px'>

Comment: OK I figured out my issue which was I am mixing html and php. So I fixed the one issue but my I have another issue which is next to each text input box I have a checkbox which if checked holds a value of yes and means that the text written in the textbox is the correct answer.

My issue is that the checkboxes are not being saved with the correct associated textbox entry. Please see my OP for the updated code